# Bisection method in CUDA

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, kernel, gpu, bisection

I was trying to implement the *Bisection Method* in CUDA. This method is capable to approximate the eigenvalues from an application ([Bisection Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)). I have some questions about how to do it.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

double f(double x)
{
    //return ((5*sin(2*x))-(52*cos(2*x)))+50;
    return cos(x);
}

double absoluto(double n){
    if(n<0)  n=n*-1; 
    return(n);
}

// Kernel CUDA
__global__ void biseccion(double *a, double *b, double *c, int n)
{
    int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    if (id < n)
        c[id] = (a[id] + b[id])/2;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int i=0;
    double malla = 1.0;
    double x1=0.0 , x2=10.0 , j=0.0;

    int n = (int)x2/(int)malla;

double *host_a;
double *host_b;
double *host_c;

double *dev_a;
double *dev_b;
double *dev_c;

size_t bytes = n*sizeof(double);

host_a = (double*)malloc(bytes);
host_b = (double*)malloc(bytes);
host_c = (double*)malloc(bytes);


cudaMalloc(&dev_a, bytes);
cudaMalloc(&dev_b, bytes);
cudaMalloc(&dev_c, bytes);



// Initialize vectors on host
for( j = 0.0; j < n; j=j+1.0 ) {
    if((f(x1)*f(x1+malla))>0){
            x1 = x1 + malla;
            i++;
    }
    else{
            host_a[i] = x1;
            host_b[i] = x1+malla;
            x1 = x1 + malla;
            i++;
    }
}

int blockSize, gridSize;
blockSize = 1024;
gridSize = (int)ceil((float)n/blockSize);

i=0;

// Copy host vectors to device
cudaMemcpy( dev_a, host_a, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy( dev_b, host_b, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// Execute the kernel
biseccion<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, n);
// Copy array back to host
cudaMemcpy( host_c, dev_c, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

i=0;
for(j=0.0;j<n;j++){
    printf("%f\n",host_c[i])
    i++;
}

// Release device memory
cudaFree(dev_a);
cudaFree(dev_b);
cudaFree(dev_c);

// Release host memory
free(host_a);
free(host_b);
free(host_c);

return 0;
}
```

The above code returns only the first aproximation, so I have to add some comparisons. For example:

if the product of `c` and `a` is negative, the new values of `a`, `b` are `a`, `c`; if not, the new values are `b`, `c` for the next iteration on the kernel and of course this must be in a loop.

My first question is how can I perform a loop in the kernel to continue the approximation?

Second, how can I implement the `if`´s to compare the values on the kernel?

Last, will the control structures like `if`´s etc. reduce the performance?

Comment: It's difficult for me to understand what you are asking.  Could you ask a question other than "any suggestions"?  You've posted a bunch of code.  Is it not working the way you expect in some way (the operation seems quite trivial)? Or are you asking how to extend this code to add some new functionality?  Perhaps you could include a wiki link to define what you mean by "bisection method" ?

Comment: Ok you are right, there are some changes, sorry, if you need anything else, just tell, p.d. Im trying hard with my engliss, because i from Mexico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to define a stop criteria or convergence criteria -- when to stop the approximations?  Let's assume your stop criteria is just a number of iterations of the bisection loop.  We can pass that as a parameter to the kernel.

Then we could re-write the kernel like this:

```
// Kernel CUDA
__global__ void biseccion(double *a, double *b, double *c, int n, int loopcnt)
{
    int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int loops = 0;
    if (id < n)
      while (loops < loopcnt){
        c[id] = (a[id] + b[id])/2;
        if ((f(c[id]) * f(a[id])) < 0) b[id] = c[id];
        else a[id] = c[id];
        loops++;
        }

}
```

I think if you study the changes I made to the kernel, you'll see it's pretty much the way you would write it in ordinary C/C++ code.

In order to make the above kernel work, we must tell the compiler that we want the `f(x)` function to be usable on either the host or the device, we do that with `__host__ __device__` decorators:

```
__host__ __device__ double f(double x)
{
    //return ((5*sin(2*x))-(52*cos(2*x)))+50;
    return cos(x);
}
```

Note that the above changes are not particularly optimized.  For example there is a considerable amount of re-use of variables that we are storing in global memory, like `a[id]`, `b[id]`, and `c[id]`.  We could make use of shared memory perhaps (or even just local thread variables -- there aren't many), and only write  the results back to global memory when we are finished with our loops.

I had to make a few other changes to your code to get things to work in a way that made sense to me.  Here's the complete modified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

__host__ __device__ double f(double x)
{
    //return ((5*sin(2*x))-(52*cos(2*x)))+50;
    return cos(x);
}

double absoluto(double n){
    if(n<0)  n=n*-1;
    return(n);
}

// Kernel CUDA
__global__ void biseccion(double *a, double *b, double *c, int n, int loopcnt)
{
    int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int loops = 0;
    if (id < n)
      while (loops < loopcnt){
        c[id] = (a[id] + b[id])/2;
        if ((f(c[id]) * f(a[id])) < 0) b[id] = c[id];
        else a[id] = c[id];
        loops++;
        }

}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int i=0;
    int loops=1000;  // this is the number of bisection iterations to run
    double malla = 1.0;
    double x1=0.0 , x2=10.0 , j=0.0;

    int n = (int)x2/(int)malla;

double *host_a;
double *host_b;
double *host_c;

double *dev_a;
double *dev_b;
double *dev_c;

size_t bytes = n*sizeof(double);

host_a = (double*)malloc(bytes);
host_b = (double*)malloc(bytes);
host_c = (double*)malloc(bytes);


cudaMalloc(&dev_a, bytes);
cudaMalloc(&dev_b, bytes);
cudaMalloc(&dev_c, bytes);


// Initialize vectors on host
while( i < n) {
    if((f(x1)*f(x1+malla))>0){
            x1 = x1 + malla;
    }
    else{
            host_a[i] = x1;
            host_b[i] = x1+malla;
            x1 = x1 + malla;
            i++;
    }
}

int blockSize, gridSize;
blockSize = 256;
gridSize = (int)ceil((float)n/blockSize);

i=0;

// Copy host vectors to device
cudaMemcpy( dev_a, host_a, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy( dev_b, host_b, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// Execute the kernel
biseccion<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, n, loops);
// Copy array back to host
cudaMemcpy( host_c, dev_c, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

i=0;
for(j=0.0;j<n;j++){
    printf("%f\n",host_c[i]);
    i++;
}

// Release device memory
cudaFree(dev_a);
cudaFree(dev_b);
cudaFree(dev_c);

// Release host memory
free(host_a);
free(host_b);
free(host_c);

return 0;
}
```

A few other notes:

- I changed your block size from 1024 to 256.  The reason I did this was to get around not having enough registers to run the kernel.  For additional description of this, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305675/cuda-double-precision-and-number-of-registers-per-thread/16368891#16368891).   This doesn't really affect anything.
- You should do [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)  on all cuda api calls and all kernel calls.
- I made some modifications to your logic for setting the inital bisection starting points.  Your method didn't make sense to me (some bisection ranges were skipped).
- I added the `loops` variable to define how many bisection loops to run.

When I run the code, I get results like this:

```
1.570796
4.712389
7.853982
10.995574
14.137167
17.278760
20.420352
23.561945
26.703538
29.845130
```

You'll note that the first result is pi/2 and each subsequent result has pi added to it, so I think this is the correct results for the first 10 roots of cos(x).

Comment: Thanx a lot!!, i can understand more about CUDA now :-)

Comment: Note that bisection halves the interval every iteration, so we should expect the final interval around the root has width (b - a)/2**n. For the bracketing strategy used here where (b-a)==1, the interval converges to double precision in at most n=52 iterations (number of mantissa bits). So while bisection can be inefficient compared to other methods, 1000 iterations is way too many for this problem. Fun fact: given an initial interval with the diameter of the observable universe, we could bisect down to the Planck length in about 205 iterations. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Robert Crovella has already pointed out that your problem was the stopping rule, which has been given in terms of the number of iterations.

For a minimally more sophisticated bisection, the stopping rule can be related also to a target accuracy. Below I'm providing a version of the bisection method in CUDA adapted from that available in the *Numerical Recipes in C++* book by which you can also set a target accuracy.

Perhaps, computationally more sophisticated bisections can be obtained by adapting the bisection kernels exploited in the `eigenvalues` CUDA SDK samples.

The new version of the method appears to be more accurate. Below some results:

```
No target accuracy

1.571289062500
4.453613281250
6.504882812500
10.546875000000
13.171386718750

Target accuracy

1.570796326795
4.712388980385
7.853981633975
10.995574287564
14.137166941154

Actual roots

1.570796326794897
4.712388980384690
7.853981633974483
10.995574287564276
14.137166941154069
```

A better initial bracketing can be achieved again by that available in the above mentioned book.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <math_constants.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 512

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
int iDivUp(int a, int b) { return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

/************************************/
/* FUNCTION TO SEARCH THE ROOTS FOR */
/************************************/
__host__ __device__ double f(double x)
{
    //return ((5*sin(2*x))-(52*cos(2*x)))+50;
    return cos(x);
}

/***************************************/
/* BISECTION KERNEL - ORIGINAL VERSION */
/***************************************/
__global__ void bisection(double *a, double *b, double *c, int N, int loopcnt)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int loops = 0;
    if (tid < N)
      while (loops < loopcnt){
        c[tid] = (a[tid] + b[tid])/2;
        if ((f(c[tid]) * f(a[tid])) < 0) b[tid] = c[tid];
        else a[tid] = c[tid];
        loops++;
        }
}

/************************************************/
/* BISECTION KERNEL - NUMERICAL RECIPES VERSION */
/************************************************/
// --- Using bisection, return the root of a function func known to lie between x1 and x2.
//     The root will be refined until its accuracy is xacc.

__global__ void bisection_NR(const double *d_x1, const double *d_x2, double *d_roots, const double xacc, const int loopcnt, const int N) {

    // --- loopcnt is the maximum allowed number of bisections.

    int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    if (tid < N) {
        double dx,xmid,rtb;

        double f1=f(d_x1[tid]);
        double fmid=f(d_x2[tid]);

        if (f1*fmid >= 0.0) d_roots[tid] = CUDART_NAN; 
        rtb = f1 < 0.0 ? (dx=d_x2[tid]-d_x1[tid],d_x1[tid]) : (dx=d_x1[tid]-d_x2[tid],d_x2[tid]); // --- Orient the search so that f>0
        for (int j=0;j<loopcnt;j++) { // --- lies at x+dx.
            fmid=f(xmid=rtb+(dx *= 0.5)); // --- Bisection loop.
            if (fmid <= 0.0) rtb=xmid;
            if (abs(dx) < xacc || fmid == 0.0) { d_roots[tid]=rtb; return; }
        }
        d_roots[tid] = CUDART_NAN;
    }
}

/*******/
/* INT */
/*******/
int main()
{
    int loops=100000;                   // --- Number of bisection iterations to run
    double x1=0.0, x2=10.0;             // --- Minimum and maximum values of the search interval
    double Deltax = 1.0;                // --- Sampling step of the search interval

    int N = (int)x2/(int)Deltax;        // --- Number of search intervales

    // --- Host-side memory allocations
    double *host_a = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    double *host_b = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    double *host_c = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));

    // --- Device-side memory allocations
    double *dev_a; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&dev_a, N*sizeof(double)));
    double *dev_b; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&dev_b, N*sizeof(double)));
    double *dev_c; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&dev_c, N*sizeof(double)));

    // --- Initialize vectors on host
    int i=0;
    while(i < N) {
        if((f(x1)*f(x1+Deltax))>0) x1 = x1 + Deltax;
        else {
            host_a[i] = x1;
            host_b[i] = x1+Deltax;
            x1 = x1 + Deltax;
            i++;
        }
    }

    // --- Copy host vectors to device
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(dev_a, host_a, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(dev_b, host_b, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    bisection<<<iDivUp(N, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, loops, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(host_c, dev_c, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%3.12f\n",host_c[i]);
    printf("\n");

    bisection_NR<<<iDivUp(N, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, 2.5e-13, loops, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(host_c, dev_c, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%3.12f\n",host_c[i]);

    // --- Release device memory
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(dev_a));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(dev_b));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(dev_c));

    // --- Release host memory
    free(host_a);
    free(host_b);
    free(host_c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice addition of the user-specified tolerance, but bisection is perfectly accurate. There's a bug where the order of `loops` and `N` are swapped on the two implementations, so the original version is only doing 10 iterations and possibly stomping memory. Fixing that, the original is more accurate (because `loops` > 52, see comment on Crovella's answer). There's another bug where the intervals (a, b) are not re-initialized, so `bisection_NR` is starting with the intervals already narrowed by the previous call to `bisection`.